# "Please provide a sheet name OR a sheet index" error

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to clean my dataset. I wrote my code yesterday and it did work well but today when I run it I get this error.
when I run this line of code I get this error

```
df = read.xlsx("C:/Users/......xlsx")
```

> Please provide a sheet name OR a sheet index.

I did not change anything at all.

how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message is saying? Try `df = read.xlsx("C:/Users/......xlsx", 1)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `sheet` argument in that function. `sheet` argument specifies either the name of the sheet(e.g. "data") or it's position in the file (e.g. 3) like so: `read.xlsx("path/to/file", sheet = 1)`

Alternatively, you could use antoher package such as the `readxl` package. Try installing it and after it's installed try `readxl::read_excel("path/to/your/data.xlsx", sheet = x)` where x is either index and name of the sheet.